# STR_TO_DATE does not exist

Tags: mysql

If I use this command in MySQL:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, users.uid AS users_uid, node.created AS node_created
FROM dr_wiwe_node node
LEFT JOIN dr_wiwe_content_type_classified node_data_field_classified_valid_till ON node.vid = node_data_field_classified_valid_till.vid
INNER JOIN dr_wiwe_users users ON node.uid = users.uid
WHERE (
(
node.type
IN (
'classified'
)
)
AND (
node.status & lt ; & gt;

0
)
) AND (
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(
node_data_field_classified_valid_till.field_classified_valid_till_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'
), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s' ) & gt ; = '2010-08-15T20:55:48'
) ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 0 , 60
```

I get error #1305 - FUNCTION DB704128.STR_TO_DATE does not exist.

But MySQL version is 5.1 anything. Where is the error?

Comment: What subversion of 5.1 is it? Maybe it wasn't supported until 5.1.2 and you have 5.1.1?

Comment: Are you sure you have a clean, working installation of the MySQL server? Maybe some of your system tables are corrupt. Try reinstalling MySQL from scratch on a test machine, and see if that installation has STR_TO_DATE.

Comment: @Meder naah, it's supported since 4.1: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: This may be relevant: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6310

Comment: @Lars can you try an arbitratry `STR_TO_DATE` call on its own, outside the complex structure?

Comment: it always returns the same error. Can I use another function instead if this one?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making your field_classified_valid_till_value field a datetime field. It makes sence to me to store fields containing times as such.

This way you won't need str_to_date and I guess it will make your query a little faster.

When you add data to the table you can then process it with PHP's strtotime function.
http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Assuming, that PHP is tha language you use to insert new Data to the database.